# Should connection pool size be same as max_connections?

Tags: database, database-connection, connection-pooling

I was wondering if in read world scenarios, does it make any sense to have connection pool size != max_connections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection pool size` is the size of always available connections whereas `max connections` is the maximum of connections.

thoroughly, it makes sense when `max connections` is bigger then the `connection pool size`. I would even say this is the standard case.

For example if you have a non regular peak in your application and you need sometimes more connections then regular. These extra connections have an initial overhead for creation but they will not strain your system after they are not needed anymore.

Generally, these settings are a decision about how many resources should be occupied permanently but therefor always available and what is the limit of occupied resources.

What makes no sense is to have a bigger `connection pool` than `max connections`.